# Как правильно пишется: бумагЕ или бумагИ?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, окончания

Ваше мнение о качестве бумагЕ  или бумагИ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Ваше мнение о качестве (чего?) бумаги (родительный падеж).

но

Ваше мнение (о чем?) о бумаге (предложный падеж).

Comment: Вот я и не могу понять. Такое предложение было написано на коробке с бумагой.  Дословно : Ваше мнение о качестве бумаге присылать.....

Comment: Пошлите им отзыв: бумага хорошая, все стерпит, даже ваши ошибки :)).